# Solving set of recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

Background: I was solving a programming problem and I got to a point where I'm trying to decide whether it is possible to solve a reccurence relation explicitly making the solution complexity better.

I have a set of two reccurence relations:
\begin{align}a_{2n+1}&=a_n+2\tag{1}\\a_{2n}&=a_n+1\tag{2}\end{align}
with $a_1=1$ and I'm trying to decide whether an explicit form exists.

Thanks.

Comment: An explicit form for $b_n$ or $a_n$?

Comment: Try writing out the first 10 elements in the sequence.

Comment: @BrianMoehring for both if possible, $b_n$ is more important to me.

Comment: What is meant by "the number of recurrence steps"? For example would $b_{20}$ be the number of times one had to use your recurrence pair on the $a_k$'s to compute $a_{20}$ on starting with $a_1$?

Comment: @aschepler I've written $b_n$ for first 200 numbers, getting no significant results...

Comment: @bof sorry, edited.

Comment: As a reference: the set of equations for $a_{n}$ can be found at [A056792](https://oeis.org/A056792)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $n$ in a binary number
$$n=\overline{c_kc_{k-1}...c_1} \qquad c_i\in\{0,1\}$$
then
$$a_n=k-1+\sum_{i=1}^kc_k \tag{1}$$

Indeed, we have
$$\begin{align}
a(\overline{c_kc_{k-1}...c_1}) &= a(\overline{c_kc_{k-1}...\color{red}{c_2}}) +2\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{ c_1 =1  \}}++1\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{ c_1 =0  \}}\\
&=a(\overline{c_kc_{k-1}...\color{red}{c_2}})+c_1+1 \tag{2}
 \end{align}$$
And $(1)$ can be deduced by recurrence from $(2)$.

Evidently, we need $k$ steps, so $b_n=k = \lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, could you please elaborate a bit more why this is the form of $a_n$? I thought I understand, but now I'm not sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Galc127 I detailed how we have the form of $a_n$, I hope the solution is clearer now.

Comment: That's great, thanks. How would the answer change for other initial value?

Comment: @Galc127 You meant the initial value of $a_1$? If yes, of course the form of $a_n$ depends on $a_1$. Just notice that $c_k$ is always equal to $1$ and so 
$$a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}c_k + (k-1) + a_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{k}}c_k + (k-1)  $$

Comment: last thing - if $c_k...c_1$ is the binary representation of n isn't $k=\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$?

Comment: @Galc127 ah yes, it should be the ceiling, not floor